# fix-broken install not working?

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, package-management, cuda

I have just tried to install the Nvidia Cuda and cudnn. But now when I try to run command `upgrade`, it shows this error:

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-drivers : Depends: cuda-drivers-550 (= 550.54.14-1) but it is not installed
 libnvidia-decode-535 : Depends: libnvidia-compute-535 (= 535.104.05-0ubuntu1) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Then I try to run `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, but gives this errors:

```
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-gl-550_550.54.14-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libnvidia-gl-535
Unpacking libnvidia-gl-550:amd64 (550.54.14-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-
gl-550_550.54.14-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-api.so.1', which is al
so in package libnvidia-extra-535:amd64 535.104.05-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local/./libnvidia-gl-550_550.54.14-0ubuntu1_amd6
4.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Then I try to remove the nvidia package by using `sudo apt purge nvidia-*`, but it still give me these errors:

```
...
...
Package 'nvidia-kernel-source-550' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-utils-530' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-utils-550' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-drivers : Depends: cuda-drivers-550 (= 550.54.14-1) but it is not going to be installed
 libnvidia-decode-535 : Depends: libnvidia-compute-535 (= 535.104.05-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Then I try `sudo apt install -f`, but still the same errors.

I want to remove and make a clean installation.

Thanks.